# Set up a root server using Ubuntu and Virtualization

Tags: virtualization, ubuntu

I'd like to setup a fresh root server and install a linux based virtualization on it.

My thoughts are on:

- Intel VTs Hardware
- Ubuntu 9.10
- KVM based virt.

The access to the root server will only be SSH for Administration. Has anybody done this before, what was your glues discovered in the daily use?

My requirements are:

- very secure, so the root server only has ssh to the dom-0 and minimalistic ports for the guest (e.g. http/s).
- good monitoring of host/guest (my idea is to using zabbix for it)
- easy and fast administration (how are the command line tools working for you? cryptiv? high learning curve?)

I'm pleased to learn from your suggestions.

Regards,

Daniel Völkerts

Comment: Why are you using Ubuntu 9.10, which is now over a year old and will soon stop being supported? I'd suggest either 10.04 (the newest LTS version, whose server version will be supported until 2015) or 10.10 (the newest version, but only supported until early 2012).

Comment: You're right the Ubuntu Version I mentioned is out dated, I'll use the 10.04 with Long Time Support. I think five years is a good round up for a servers lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there, either use 10.04 or 10.10 (virtualization stuff still changes quite often, so a newer server release might not be that bad). I'd say try KVM virtualization (just since all distro testing and QA go to KVM nowadays not XEN). You can use virt-manager GUI tool for remote management of VMs. Probably setup LVM on the virt host, and setup a LVM logical volume for each guest (that way you can have LVM snapshots and backups for your guests).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use the latest version of ubuntu, or or even CentOS, (which is very stable, and changes less than ubuntu does), and make a mental note to remember not to update as often as you work an ubuntu desktop. Just update packages.

If you are going to only use SSH for administration, I would suggest that you use ssh keys to connect to it. Also, remember to install virt-manager and x-auth - this will allow you to use a GUI to manage your virtual servers.

Just my few comments.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. SSH keys are a good idea. Would you forward the ports for managment GUIs?